# Is using 'restore' command to restore rdb file possible?

Tags: redis

all
I see the doc in http://redis.io/commands/dump, that the result of `dump` command

> Values are encoded in the same format used by RDB.

So, is that possible to recovery data from rdb file with `restore` command?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

No - the [`RESTORE`](http://redis.io/commands/restore) command is indeed [`DUMP`](http://redis.io/commands/dump)'s complement but it only works on a single key. An RDB file, on the other hand, is potentially made up of multiple keys and is loaded only when the Redis server starts.

Comment: what if I analysis an rdb file and select specific key and value then build them as a `restore` command? thx

Comment: Should work but that's not what you asked in the original question ;)